# AwesomeWM non-ascii character doesn't display

Tags: bash, unicode, lua, awesome-wm

In my `wibox` taskbar, I have a `wibox.widget.textbox` whose text is set using the `textbox:set_text` method.

The text comes from a bash command, whose output is recieved with `io:popen()`:

```
local fd = io.popen("sensors | grep -oP 'Physical\\s+id\\s+\\d+:\\s+\\+\\K[0-9.]+'")
local out = fd:read("*all")
fd:close()    
temp_widget:set_text(out)
```

However, `out` contains a non-ascii symbol: the degree character °.

And in my taskbar, this character is displayed as �, which is itself a unicode character: `U+FFFD`. So I presume that awesome supports unicode, so why this char isn't displaying correctly?

EDIT: Also, as a side problem, I can't append a string to my output. IE, if I do `temp_widget:set_text(out .. "foobar")`, the result is the same as `temp_widget:set_text(out)`. How to append a string then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with removing the degree sign from my `grep` string, and appending it again in lua. So the font wasn't the problem, nor the widget assuming the encoding was not unicode.

**l0b0** was right about the out ending with a new line though, it solved my second problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe "�" is not necessarily U+FFFD, but also a **generic replacement character** for any character not in the font you're using. So the problem might simply be one of font support. For example, if I go to a [random web page whose title contains a degree sign](https://unicode-table.com/en/00B0/) the browser title bar contains a degree sign. Another possibility is that since **[Lua strings do not have an explicit encoding](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaUnicode)** you might have to somehow tell the widget which encoding it should assume for input.

As for concatenating strings, are you sure that `out` doesn't end with a newline, causing the subsequent string to be hidden because it's out of bounds? `grep` output always ends with a newline, even if the match does not:

```
$ echo ab | grep -o a | xxd -pu
610a
```